# My network service (netsvcs) seems to be hogging all my memory

Tags: windows-7, networking, services

*Before everyone goes complain that I should wait for Windows 10, don't. Because I'm sure high school/university assignments will NEVER get a 2-4 month extension.*

Operating System: Windows 7, Service Pack 1 Home Premium
Laptop Model: Acer Aspire 5742
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-370M, clocked at 2.4Ghz
RAM: 2GB (2x 1GB DDR3 sticks), true value is about 1.9GB.
*I'm sure you don't need to know everything else..*

---

Basically this (not the worse) happens:
[image: It gets up to 1GB, but you get the idea...]
*It can at times get up to 1.4GB, but you get the idea.*

My network service seems to be using a lot of memory, even when there are no programs that require network access open. And by 'a lot', I meant at least 50% to all of my avaliable RAM (1.4GB at most, without any other program running), to the point that all my applications would crash and the computer would hang for up to two hours until netsvcs actually died down back to the '50% of avaliable memory range'.

This problem persists even when the computer is not connected to a network, and sometimes happens at startup (after logging in), and it happens every 30 minutes, for about 20 minutes during the entire duration that the computer is turned on (and a user is logged in).

What seems to be wrong? (I'll post a picture when I can)

Comment: looks like WindowsUpdate scans for new updates. My WindowsUpdate on Win8 also uses over 1GB RAM during scan.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Can't be Windows Update, since I've set it to check every day at 2AM. So, "every 30 minutes" is definitely not "once a day". | Will update question to reflect this statement, since I forgot to include it.

Comment: That svchost process consists of numerous system services, many of which have nothing to do with "networking". You could use Process Explorer from Microsoft/Sysinternals to see exactly which ones. Among them is the task scheduler service (which would explain the "every 30 minutes" thing, so you could look thru the list of the scheduled tasks on your system. I don't know why you are getting app crashing and freezes, cuz that svchost sometimes uses over 50% of my physical memory at times, with no such problems observed. Maybe you just have a lot of buggy apps.

Comment: capture a xperf trace (1-2 minutes) of the memory usage and share it: http://pastebin.com/yLvYak6n

Comment: have you captured the xperf trace?

Comment: Er.. No - I somehow managed to disable it... (At the cost of all connections other than HTTP and HTTPS; all MP games, online features and updates disabled) and now I've forgotten how to undo it. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I'll leave it up for a few more days before deleting it. Since it's "solved". (And you need to see the message @magicandre1981)

Comment: **don't delete the question**. Post your finding as answer and accept the answer.

Comment: @magicandre1981 It's not a proper solution though. It doesn't fix the problem - It circumvents the problem. It's like "walk around the wall" instead of "use a drill to drill a hole in the wall".

Comment: My laptop is doing exactly the same thing. Netsvcs, when I run windows update it goes from 20mb to 700+.

Comment: @Stuntbeaver, try disabling any program that requires Windows Installer (MSI), installs something to the system, and programs like Steam and Windows Update... And not like me where I've blocked all ports but 80 and 443.